# the relationship between the number of filters/kernels and the number of feature maps

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

[image: Hierarchical Models Of Perception and Reasoning by Yann LeCun]

The above image is from "[Deep Learning Tutorial](https://cs.nyu.edu/~yann/talks/lecun-ranzato-icml2013.pdf)" by Yann LeCun and Marc'Aurelio Ranzato (see pages 73 and 81).

**I don't understand why 64 kernels (from the input to layer 1) produce 64 feature maps while 4096 kernels (layer 2 to layer 3) give 256 feature maps.**

Comment: The discussion & examples here might be helpful http://cs231n.github.io/convolutional-networks/#conv

Comment: @desertnaut thanks, but in the link you provided, it says K filters correspond to K feature maps. That's why I don't understand how 4096 kernels (layer 2 to layer 3) give 256 feature maps in LeCun's slices.

Comment: It seems that your question is focused on machine learning, and is not directly related to programming, making it off-topic here. You may find that [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com) or [Data Science SE](https://datascience.stackexchange.com) are a better fit for these questions.